# What is the opposite of "to make a bed"?

Tags: terminology

Is it "to turn down a bed"? Like when you wake up you make your bed, what do you do before you go to bed?

Comment: "Turndown" sounds fine there. The hotel industry uses the term [turndown service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turndown_service).

Comment: @Lawrence what about a household term and all the other terms that people use?

Comment: One can ["turn down" the sheets](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/turn%20down) (definition 28). It's fine for everyday communication.

Comment: I would have said the opposite is to “muss it up”.  Do people really  turn down their beds at home?